# Map "Super+ArrowDown" to minimize a window while the window is focused & the window is not in fullscreen

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 19.10, remapping

I would like to add a conditional key mapping to Ubuntu 19.10.

Normally when a window is in full screen mode and you press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>arrowDown</kbd> it enters window mode (or whatever it is called).

When a window now is in "window mode" I would like to be able to minimise it (and only then) by using <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>arrowDown</kbd> on it.

Is it possible to create such a shortcut without affecting the mapping of <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>arrowDown</kbd> on full screen windows?

Comment: Oh, forgot about that 19.10

Comment: @K7AAY thank you for the nice edit!

Comment: More editing tips are at https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code and Amis are taught here not to correct proper Commonwealth spelling of minimise , et al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following Bash script to the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> shortcut.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
active_window_id=$(printf 0x%x "$(xdotool getactivewindow)")
window_state=$(xprop -id "$active_window_id" | grep "_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM)")

if [[ "$window_state" == *"MAXIMIZED"* ]]; then
    wmctrl -ir "$active_window_id" -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
else
    xdotool windowminimize "$active_window_id"
fi
```

The script uses `xdotool`, `wmctrl` and `xprop`. Make sure they are installed in your computer by running:

```
sudo apt install xdotool wmctrl x11-utils
```

**To save the script and make it executable:**

1. Open the text editor of your choice and copy/paste the content of the script.
2. Save the script somewhere on your computer with a name of your choice, for example as `/home/user/path/to/script.sh`.
3. Give execution rights to the script you saved by running:

   ```
   chmod u+x /home/user/path/to/script.sh
   ```

**To add the script to a shortcut (in GNOME):**

1. Open *Settings* → *Devices* → *Keyboard*.
2. Find the *Restore window* shortcut, click on it and set it to another shortcut, for example <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, and press *Set*. This has to be done or else you won't be able to use the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> for the script.
   **Note:** If you wish <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to have the default behavior and set the script to another shortcut, skip this step and add the shortcut of your choice following the next steps.
3. At the bottom of the keyboard shortcuts window click on the "+" icon to add a new shortcut.
4. Give the shortcut a name of your choice, for example "Minimize alternative", add the full path to the script (`/home/user/path/to/script.sh`) in the *Command* field, click *Set Shortcut...* to add <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> as the shortcut and close the shortcut window (see screenshot below).

   [image: Shortcut setting]

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> should now have the behavior you want!

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed solution, works pretty well. Only one small notice: the xprop tool seems to be part of some other "bundle" and isn't available in standard apt repos by itself (At least not for me). I was somewhat lucky since it was already installed on my system but just wanted to mention it since you wrote this detailed and precise manual that basically everybody no matter how experienced they are can use.

Comment: You are right! `xprop` comes bundled with the `x11-utils` package, which should be preinstalled in all Ubuntu versions. I've changed that in my answer. Thanks for noticing that!

Answer (score 1):

To change only that, you probably would need to write your own extension. However, there is an extension that behaves like you want, besides doing some other things. It is the Gnome Shell extension [WinTile: Windows 10 window tiling for GNOME](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1723/wintile-windows-10-window-tiling-for-gnome/) by Fmstrat.

It does exacty what you want, where <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> will take the window out of maximized mode, and a subsequent press will minimize it.

It does extra things, but them, you might like these. You can tile left and right as in standard Ubuntu with the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> keys. In addition, using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> on a half tiled window will quarter tile it.